# Python variables in other variables

Tags: php, python, mysql, variables

I'm kind of new in python and want to make a MySQL select.

I want to select from the MySQL and add a variable to the query like this:

```
date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d)
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date='%s'" % date
```

(This offcourse, doesn't work)
I'm used to Php so this is kind of new to me as you can see :)

THANKS!

Comment: Which SQL library are you using?

Comment: which library / module are you using to access mySQL?. you can look at SQLAlchemy if you are interested in an amazing ORM!

Comment: and why do you think it does not work? the query is fine..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking for the validity of your SELECT statement, or are you asking how perform a MySQL query in python?

Comment: @Wes - In think he's asking how to use prepared statements in Python. He should probably clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this does what you want...

```
date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d)
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date= '%s' "
sql = sql % (date)
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: I assumed you were using `MySQLdb` for python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
now = time.localtime()
date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date='%s'" % date
```

I think this fragment does what you want?

Hope this helps